# Emulator Wifi is not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin app using Visual studio 2015 enterprise.

[image]

Issue is that my emulator wifi is not connecting where as internet is working in my system. Please provide me the way or link through which we can solve this issue.

Comment: I don't know about Visual Studio emulators, but you can use genymotion emulator.

Comment: but i have an issue in Visual studio emulator

Comment: This is most likely going to be the result of a problem with your virtual network adapter settings in Windows. When you install the VS emulators, it adds some virtual adapters there that need to be enabled and configured correctly. It usually does this for you but sometimes it messes up.

Which version of Windows are you running?

Comment: I am using windows 8 and before emulators were working good but now it is giving issue. Can you please tell me how i will set the settings so that it will work